# First order spatial derivatives in Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, differentiation

So far all Hamiltonians I have come across have a separate kinetic and potential term. The kinetic term consists of a second order derivative term and the potential is a function of the co-ordinates. This is the generic form of the Hamiltonians used both in the classical domain and the quantum domain.

My question therefore is: What does it mean for a quantum mechanical system to have a first order derivative term (in terms of spatial coordinates; a derivative in time would simply indicate dissipation) in the Hamiltonian? Is it possible to extract potential-like information from the differential form of the Hamiltonian in that case?

Comment: Spatial derivatives? In what sense? Do you just mean momentum? Maybe provide an example? Are you referring to QFT rather than QM?

Comment: Not necessarily. I am talking about a hypothetical Hamiltonian which besides containing the usual second order derivative (the kinetic term), also contains a first order spatial derivative term. Whether or not one can extract a field theory out of it is a different issue altogether, I believe.

Comment: That's just the Schrödinger representation of the momentum operator.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate examples that come to mind are [Rashba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashba_effect) ($H_R \propto (\mathbf{p}\times\boldsymbol{\sigma}) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{z}}$) and (linear) Dresshelhaus spin-orbit couplings ($H_D \propto \mathbf{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}$; I can't seem to find a good reference), which occur in 2D. These allow you form spin-currents (cf spin-Hall effect), since different momenta couple with different spin directions. The appearance of a linear term in $\mathbf{p}$ means requires that the system must break spatial inversion symmetry. Of course, this is also true of any higher order odd term in $\mathbf{p}$.

I am not sure if there is any deeper interpretation, in the same way time derivatives give dissipation. If you have a purely have a Hamiltonian $H = a\mathbf{p}^2 + b\mathbf{p}$, for example, you can always rewrite it as $H = a(\mathbf{p} + \frac{b}{2a})^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}$, which merely constitutes a linear shift in the momentum so does not give any qualitatively new dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

A derivative term in the quantum-mechanical Hamiltonian is equivalent to a momentum term in the classical Hamiltonian, so I will discuss this in classical terms (although classically, it's actually simplest to look a the Lagrangian).

The nonrelativistic Hamiltonian for a single particle can be generically written $H=\frac{1}{2m}(\vec{p}-\vec{A})^{2}+V(\vec{r})$.  This includes an arbitrary term that is linear in $\vec{p}$, which has been rewritten slightly by completing the square.  The linear term is parameterized by function $A(\vec{x},t)$, which is the vector potential for a magnetic field (in units with $q=c=1$).  If you derive the equations of motion, you will find the Lorentz force law for $m\ddot{\vec{x}}$.  (Note, however, that Hamilton's equation for 
$\dot{\vec{x}}$ tells you that $\vec{p}\neq m\dot{\vec{x}}$, but rather $\vec{p}=m\dot{\vec{x}}+\vec{A}$.)  The electric and magnetic fields that appear are given by the usual formulas $\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V-\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}$ and $\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$.